# data("autocomplete") is undefined in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, typescript

I use this code in my app (to override `_renderItem`);

```
var ac: JQuery = $("<input/>");
ac.addClass(this._autocompleteId);
ac.appendTo(container);
ac.autocomplete(options);

var renderItem = (ul: JQuery, item: Label) => {
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append($("<a></a>").html(item.label))
        .appendTo(ul);
};

ac.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = renderItem;
```

And the problem is `ac.data("autocomplete")` is `undefined`. I don't know why, because I was using this code before. The bug appeared after I have updated `JQuery 1.8` and `JQueruUI 1.9` libs to the newest versions...

**[edit]**

Ok, I have found a solution for this. In the new version of `JQueryUI`, `autocomplete` was changed to `ui-autocomplete`. So it works:

```
ac.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = renderItem;
```

I leave this post, because someone may need this in the future:)

Comment: Where do you define `ac.data("autocomplete")`?

Comment: Isn't autocomplete an element of JQuery? I think `ac.autocomplete(options);` defines it. Btw. as I said, it had been working before the update. What changed that is no more correct?

Comment: Just remember to answer your own question and mark it as accepted, this way it will not be reported as unanswered :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution for this. In the new version of `JQueryUI`, `autocomplete` was changed to `ui-autocomplete`. So it works:

```
ac.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = renderItem;
```